# Prevent other processes for performance

Tags: apt, dpkg, cpu, process

Let's say I have an .c and .cpp file which runs some code to calculate the duration of some process;

Basically I get microseconds between some method and I calculate how many seconds does this method take. But I am wondering about if any other process ( such as updating something behind ) effects these microseconds and I want to know how to prevent other processes to effect this calculation.

In short, please explain me to prevent other processes in order to get exact measure of my method call of .c file.

Can you please help me?
Thanks

Comment: One approach might be to repeat the measuring N times and then take the average.

Comment: @PerlDuck No, when measuring code performance, given that the input and environment is constant, you should take the shortest time you measured instead of the average. A process doesn't randomly get faster than it can be, there can only be influences slowing it down.

Comment: @ByteCommander Agree. But it depends on what you want to measure: the _usual_ time a process takes or the _shortest_ time it takes. It may or may not help to know that a process takes time X when running as the sole process and thus can occupy all CPUs. However, the OP actually asked something I didn't help with anyway: how to make a process not being influenced by others with regard to execution performance.

Answer (score 2):

As root, you can start applications with higher scheduling priority by setting a low niceness value. This can be done using the `nice` command, like:

```
sudo nice -n -20 your_command
```

-20 is the highest priority you can give, 0 is default, 19 is lowest. See `man nice` for more info.

This will make the CPU scheduler prefer your process over others, if both are ready to run and requesting CPU time. It does not prevent other processes from running while your process is not using 100% CPU time, which you also would not want anyway.

Note however that this will also run your command as root, and also that setting high priority to a process that consumes all CPU time can make your system unresponsive.

---

Other than that, as mentioned in the comments, to measure the runtime of your command, let it run several times under the same conditions (equal input and environment, so that in a perfect world, the process would do 100% the exact same thing) and take the shortest time you got as your actual measurement value. Environmental factors may slow your application down, but not really speed it up, so the fastest run is the one with least influence from outside.

You should not only take CPU usage into account though, but especially disk read/write performance is also a quite important factor. For precise and reproducible measuring, you should not perform any real hard disk operations but operate in RAM only, reading your application and data from there and also performing any writes only to RAM. You can mount a RAM disk that acts like a normal file system to e.g. `/mnt` (or anywhere else) using:

```
sudo mount -t tmpfs none /mnt
```

Comment: so with a priority level at 20, doesn't make a problem if we want to interrupt the program with the terminal (which has a basic priority level)?

Comment: I am not sure how exactly the scheduler is implemented and whether -20 would mean that no other process ever gets to run if yours is spinning on 100% (e.g. if you try to calculate a billion digits of Pi), but it's fairly possible that your shell would not get scheduled any more in that situation, causing you to be unable to interrupt it. That's why I said it can make your system unresponsive. You can also just use a slightly higher priority like -5 or -10, that should be more safe.

Answer (score 0):

Use dedicated CPU core for your process. It's possible to isolate a CPU core from system processes using 2 basic methods:

1. Add the parameter `isolcpus=[cpu_number]` to the Linux kernel - [read more...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13583146/whole-one-core-dedicated-to-single-process)
2. Use `cpuset` - [read more...](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man7/cpuset.7.html)